# Different responses of Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Consider this code

```
f[x_, y_, t_] := t Sin[2 Pi x] + 2 t Sin[2 Pi y]
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[f[x, y, t], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}], {t, 
  1, 2}]
```

If we change the value of parameter `t` by clicking on the slider then the plot is evaluated almost instantly. But, if we use the control button to change the value of `t`, Mathematica needs few moments to draw the surface. This is definitely an anomaly on how `Manipulate` works. I propose this problem should be addressed as bug so it can be fixed in the future release. I run Mathematica 10.4 Win 10 64bit on Intel i7 with 8GB or RAM. I am sure my machine is powerful enough to plot.

Comment: Interesting observation; I can reproduce it in v. 10.4; however, you can simply set `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` and both methods of changing the parameter will behave the same way.

Comment: I don't observe the behavior. The performance could be considered slow, but it seems pretty much the same time to respond in either case. (~0.15s on the crappy display, ~0.22s on the Retina display, V10.4, Mac)

Comment: Your plot is clipped for the larger values of `t` because of the specified `PlotRange`. Recommend that you use `PlotRange -> range` where `range = (#[{f[x, y, t], 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1, 1 <= t <= 2}, {x, y, t}][[1]]& /@ {Minimize, Maximize});`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that *Mathematica* is continuously trying to draw your 3D plot over-and-over again as you move the slider thumb (what you call the control button) and it can't keep up. To get better behavior, I suggest you add the option `ContinuousAction -> False` -- like so:

```
f[x_, y_, t_] := t Sin[2 Pi x] + 2 t Sin[2 Pi y]
Manipulate[
  Plot3D[f[x, y, t], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}],
  {t, 1, 2},
  ContinuousAction -> False]
```

This will make moving the slider thumb work in the same way as clicking in the slider channel by suppressing the plot redraw while the thumb is moving.

Comment: By control button I mean the buttons with plus and minus sign.

Comment: Actually MarcoB's solution fixes the issue.